# Getting memory warning when inserting into database with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, concurrency

I'm going to explain my scenario:

I have a couple of entities in my data model which have a to-many relationship between them, let's say they are `EntityA` and `EntityB`. I request all those entities' data to a REST service, I receive all information in JSON format, I parse it and I then create the corresponding objects.

Services' requests are performed asynchronously, and I store the objects I finally get in two `NSMutableArray`, one for `EntityA` objects and another for `EntityB` objects. Once I have all the objects, I add the objects of `EntityB` to the `NSSet` in `EntityA` that models the relationship as needed. In the end, I save the context.

The problem I find is that I get a large amount of `EntityB` objects from service (5000 objects aprox), and I get a memory warning even parsing and inserting in separated threads like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(dataLoadQueue, NULL);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator = [self.context persistentStoreCoordinator];
                NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
                [tmpContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator];

                __block int count=0;

                for (NSDictionary *item in self.JSONObjects) {
                    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(dataParseQueue, NULL);
                    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                        EntityB *entityB = [entitiesDao createEntityB:item];

                        if (entityB != nil) {
                            [self insertEntityB:entityB inContext:tmpContext];
                            [self.entityBArray addObject:entityB];
                        }

                        count++;
                    });
                }

                if (count == self.JSONObjects.count) {

                    for (EntityB *entityB in self.entityBArray) {
                            [self linkEntityA:[entityB.entityAId integerValue] toEntityB:entityB];
                    }

                    [self.context save:nil];
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //finalization
                });
            });
```

I need to store all objects in arrays to later create the relationship between them, and to save the model with the relationships in database. I don't know a better way to do this, could somebody help me? How could I avoid having a memory warning in this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not maintain multiple copies of your data in arrays. You have the JSON object already. Also, you only need one background thread - or maybe you can just put up an activity indicator for a couple of seconds and not bother with background threads.

Just first create your entity entityA objects and save the context. Then create your entityB objects and retrieve the entityA objects as needed to set the relationships.

I did something like this with more than 100.000 records (JSON string app. 60MB) on a first generation iPad without problems.

An effective memory management technique is also to enclose the critical parts in autorelease pools.

```
@autorelease {
   // memory intensive operation, e.g. in a loop
}
```

*NB: For performance reasons it is often advisable to save in batches, say every 500-1000 records inserted.*